# Numpy only way to read text file and keep comments

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a minimal working example of a text file:

```
# A B C
1 7 9
7 2 10
10 20 30
```

Loading this file using [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) will discard the commented line. Is there a nice way to map the columns stored as a comment into an array that I can use for access? It is very easy to do this with a few lines of standard python, reading, parsing, splitting and mapping to an array, but I was looking for a built-in command and it seems that both `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` throw away all comments. I have an inkling that this might be what pandas is for and an answer that uses another library for data management is OK too.

Comment: What do you mean with "an array that I can use for access"? What would be the result you would like to get?

Comment: @javidcf What I have is a large collection of text files where the last row of the comments is a mapping of each column to a logical name describing the column. I simply would like an array of `["A","B","C"]` to be returned, but an object that could be accessed like `X["A"]["C"]` would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it can be done, first read in a single line, extract the column headings into a list, re-read it in again, skipping the initial row, passing `header = None` and then set the column names after skipping the first element:

```
In [78]:
import io
import pandas as pd
temp="""# A B C
1 7 9
7 2 10
10 20 30"""

cols = list(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+', nrows=1))
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+', skiprows=1, header=None)
df.columns = cols[1:]
df
Out[78]:
    A   B   C
0   1   7   9
1   7   2  10
2  10  20  30
```

Comment: I take it `io.StringIO` is just to handle the fact that you have a string in the program right? If you were reading it from a file on disk it looks like you can just pass the filename, correct?

Comment: @Hooked yes that is correct, so in your case it would be something like `df = pd.read_csv('myData.txt',.....)`

Answer (score 3):

You're right about pandas! Here is the file `r.txt` (note I removed the `#`):

```
A B C
1 7 9
7 2 10
10 20 30
```

And here is the code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> i = pd.read_csv('r.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
>>> i
    A   B   C
0   1   7   9
1   7   2  10
2  10  20  30

[3 rows x 3 columns]
>>> i["A"][0]
1
```

Comment: If you remove the `#`, `genfromtxt` can use the 1st line for headers - field names - with `names=True`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the comment character doesn't bother `genfromtxt`.  It can still treat that 1st line as a source for names, and load the data as a structured array.

```
In [189]: s="""\
# A B C
1 7 9
7 2 10
10 20 30
"""
In [190]: X=np.genfromtxt(s.splitlines(),names=True)
In [191]: X
Out[191]: 
array([(1.0, 7.0, 9.0), (7.0, 2.0, 10.0), (10.0, 20.0, 30.0)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
In [192]: X.dtype.names
Out[192]: ('A', 'B', 'C')
In [193]: X['A']
Out[193]: array([  1.,   7.,  10.])
In [194]: X[1]
Out[194]: (7.0, 2.0, 10.0)
```